# how to use show/hide items with 2 columns in a Spotfire crosstable

Tags: spotfire

I have a crosstable and I am using 2 calculated columns A and B in the my cross table. Above the crosstable I have 2 slider property controls. I am using both of these sliders are thresholds. 
I want to only show values in the crosstable when the Column A's value >= threshold1 and Column B's value is also >= its own threshold2.

I am using Show/hide items, which works just fine with 1 column. So lets say if I apply the condition Column A >= threshold1 it displays the data properly as soon as implement the 2nd rule for Column B >= threshold2. Its stops working.
Could someone help me resolve this?

You can take a look the the filters I am talking about in the link here [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RW43Z.png) 
I have labeled 2 filters, I am trying to limit the output by these filters. 
Here is the screenshot of what I am trying to do. [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAs7g.png)
For some reason both the rules are not working together. I can only apply one of them.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you tried using the same threshold in Limit data using custom expressions?

Comment: Hello and thank you.

Comment: The option you have provided wont work because I want the limitation to be applied after the fact. The limit data using custom expression will limit the data even before the calculations are made, which is not what I am trying to do. Once the custom expression is used to create the column, I want to apply the limitations on that. I hope this makes sense. Please let me know if I can do this

Comment: @rohit bhatia - Could you please post a screenshot with some sample data which will give us an idea as why your solution isn't working?

Comment: @ksp585 I have added the screenshots in the description of the problem above. Thank you for your help

Comment: @rohit bhatia - In response to the comment from scsimon, you mentioned that 'Once the custom expression is used to create the column, I want to apply the limitations on that.' - Could you give us more details on this? I tried the below expression in 'Limit data using expression' as per scsimon's comment, which worked.                 [current increase]>=${threshold1} and [prior increase]>=${threshold2}

Comment: @ksp585 - The columns Current increase and prior increase are created in the custom expression (cell values) of the cross table. They are not available in the underlying table. So I cannot use the condition [current increase]>=${threshold1} and [prior increase]>=${threshold2}